# Email markup not working

Tags: gmail, google-schemas, json-ld

I'm trying to send a Flight confirmation email with markups in order to get highlighted the flight information in Gmail.

This is the markup:

```html
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    [       
            {
            "@context": "http://schema.org",
            "@type": "FlightReservation",
            "reservationNumber": "PNR TEST",
            "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
            "underName": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "Prenom Nom"
            },
            "reservationFor": {
            "@type": "Flight",
            "flightNumber": "2712",
            "airline": {"@type": "Airline","name": "IBERIA","iataCode": "IB"},
            "departureAirport": {"@type": "Airport","name": "Madrid","iataCode": "MAD"},
            "departureTime": "Tue Sep 08 06:50:00 CEST 2015",
            "arrivalAirport": {"@type": "Airport","name": "Barcelona","iataCode": "BCN"},
            "arrivalTime": "Tue Sep 08 08:00:00 CEST 2015"
            }
            },          
            {
            "@context": "http://schema.org",
            "@type": "FlightReservation",
            "reservationNumber": "PNR TEST",
            "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
            "underName": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "Prenom Nom"
            },
            "reservationFor": {
            "@type": "Flight",
            "flightNumber": "2739",
            "airline": {"@type": "Airline","name": "IBERIA","iataCode": "IB"},
            "departureAirport": {"@type": "Airport","name": "Barcelona","iataCode": "BCN"},
            "departureTime": "Thu Sep 10 06:50:00 CEST 2015",
            "arrivalAirport": {"@type": "Airport","name": "Madrid","iataCode": "MAD"},
            "arrivalTime": "Thu Sep 10 08:10:00 CEST 2015"
            }
            }   ]
</script>
```

When I don't include this markup in the email, gmail is showing flight info automatically, but sometimes there is some wrong info.

Now, when I include the markup, that passes the [Google Markup Test](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/), Gmail doesn't show Flight Highlight. I have tried it with my personal account as sender and as recipient in order to ignore the registration requirements, like I have read [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/testing-your-schema), but this is not working.

Could you give me some indication?

Answer (score 1):

Your [DateTime](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/datetime-formatting) formatting is not correct. Per the documentation:

*(DateTime values are expected to be in the ISO 8601 format, for example '2013-02-14T13:15:03-08:00' (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ).*

When I tested your markup, I wasn't able to generate anything in [Inbox](https://inbox.google.com), however, when I changed the **departureTime** and **arrivalTime** attributes in your markup, I was able to generate actions.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
    [       
            {
            "@context": "http://schema.org",
            "@type": "FlightReservation",
            "reservationNumber": "PNR TEST",
            "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
            "underName": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "Prenom Nom"
            },
            "reservationFor": {
            "@type": "Flight",
            "flightNumber": "2712",
            "airline": {"@type": "Airline","name": "IBERIA","iataCode": "IB"},
            "departureAirport": {"@type": "Airport","name": "Madrid","iataCode": "MAD"},
            "departureTime": "2015-10-20T13:15:03-08:00",
            "arrivalAirport": {"@type": "Airport","name": "Barcelona","iataCode": "BCN"},
            "arrivalTime": "2015-10-20T18:15:03-08:00"
            }
            },          
            {
            "@context": "http://schema.org",
            "@type": "FlightReservation",
            "reservationNumber": "PNR TEST",
            "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
            "underName": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "Prenom Nom"
            },
            "reservationFor": {
            "@type": "Flight",
            "flightNumber": "2739",
            "airline": {"@type": "Airline","name": "IBERIA","iataCode": "IB"},
            "departureAirport": {"@type": "Airport","name": "Barcelona","iataCode": "BCN"},
            "departureTime": "2015-10-21T13:15:03-08:00",
            "arrivalAirport": {"@type": "Airport","name": "Madrid","iataCode": "MAD"},
            "arrivalTime": "2015-10-21T18:15:03-08:00"
            }
            }   ]
</script>
```

You should get the following result, you'll notice the 2nd notification (Barcelona to Madrid) below it as well:

[image]